# Is there a way to limit a dropdown box size

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to build my site and the dropdown I am using is too long for the page so some items cannot be seen, is there any way to, limit the length it can go to before needing the user to scroll, I have attached an image to show what I mean as well as the code I am currently using
[image: Image showing the dropdown issue]

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="../category.php">Search By Category:</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <?php echo $htmlResult1; ?>
                              </ul>
```

The main results are brought in via php but follow the correct style to be listed

Any thoughts

Comment: the image stops at the bottom as this is the bottom of the screen

Comment: Set a `max-height` and `overflow` to `<ul>`

Comment: @LuisP.A. I've added your comment as a community wiki answer. If you add your own answer, I'll delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Luis P.A. said:

> Set a `max-height` and `overflow` to `<ul>`

```
ul.dropdown-menu {
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto; /*scroll results in a scrollbar even when the height < 400px */
}
```

Comment: No problem..You did well :)

Answer (score 1):

set the max-height and overflow attributes in your CSS

```
 .fixedHeight-ddl{
        height: auto;
        max-height: 300px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```

and your tag

```
class="dropdown-menu fixedHeight-ddl"
```